# How to implement the $in query in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I want a subset of users from all users, whose id is present in a list. In mongodb this would be done using the $in query. Not sure how to do this in Firebase. As there would be millions of users, it doesn't make sense to load all users and then filter them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [FirebaseIndex](https://github.com/Zenovations/FirebaseIndex). From the github intro:

> FirebaseIndex is a simple proxy that allows large Firebase data sets to be filtered, sorted, and retrieved by an index (a list of keys) 
>   http://zenovations.github.com/FirebaseIndex/